# ASP.NET Core Web Application integrate TcpSockets

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets, asp.net-core, signalr

I have 2 Blazor WA apps and 2 ASP.NET Core Web Application servers which communicate via SignalR (one Blazor WA talks to one ASP.NET Core Web Application server, and another Blazor WA talks to it's ASP.NET Core Web Application servers).

I need both servers to communicate using sockets so I can share/notify when a changed happened to a server.

The only thing I could find is implementation of sockets using console app. But in that case I could not see any up-to-date example of console app and SignalR solution.

[Repository](https://github.com/eugeniuRacila/minimum-uber-clone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good morning mate.

I understand what you want to do, you can use a 3rd application that can be the rabbitmq, messaging system.

Take a look at rabbitmq and forget about the socket.

Note: the communication I speak is backend -> backend;

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Can I do that using ASP.NET Core Web Application servers which I have at the moment (I mean to integrate RabbitMQ)?

Comment: Yes, it can be integrated, and it is very easy to integrate

can you take a look at a project of mine

https://github.com/srburton/dotnet.boilerplate

RabbitMq INTEGRATION:
/src/Infra/Integration/App.Infra.Integration.RabbitMq/